# Proving what failed a simple inequality test?

Tags: inequality

Prove that:
$\frac{b-a}{1+b^2}<\tan^{-1}b-\tan^{-1}a<\frac{b-a}{1+a^2}$

If $a < b$

Inequality test:

Let $a=15$, $b=20$  then  $15 < 20$

$\frac{20-15}{1+20^2}<\tan^{-1}20-\tan^{-1}15<\frac{20-15}{1+15^2}$
$0.012<0.9516<0.022$ 
of course this is completely out of context...

could there have been something I missed or the question itself is completely erroneous??

Comment: Try to divide by (b-a) the middle term is similar to the slope of the bisection between (a,f(a)),(b,f(b)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you missed:  you should have used radians instead of degrees.